# Automatic Facebook Page creation for my website users

Tags: facebook, performance

Is there a way to link my company website directly to Facebook so that when users sign on my company website which has thousands of hits each day, it could also automatically create them a Facebook page for there company. The website is www.buildingtrades.com and is a nationwide association for contractors. We have a form on there for people to join our association online and upon completing the form, we would like to have it also create them a Facebook page automatically as one of our services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to create a facebook page programmatically, but you can treat any webpage as a page: see [here](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/04/21/with-the-open-graph-protocol-any-url-can-be-treated-just-like-a-facebook-page/) for more information